# Minimum message query pricing on google-cloud-iot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, price, google-cloud-iot

On the google cloud IoT pricing site, it says the `minimum message size` is **1024 bytes**.

Does this mean:

- IOT-core **does not** permit message of less than 1024 bytes
- IOT-core charges the cost of 1024 bytes for any messages **less than 1024 bytes**
- Something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It means that it'll charge for 1024 bytes per message even if the message is smaller.